# Kotlin: Using method reference to a getter of another class

Tags: kotlin

I have a class -

```
class ES {
    var issue: SomeClass? = null
}
```

I need to access its getter in another class -

```
class CSS {
   private val ref: Supplier<SomeClass?> = ES::issue
}
```

However this is not working. Its throws this error -

```
Type mismatch.
Required: Supplier<SomeClass?>
Found   : KMutableProperty1<ES, SomeClass?>
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong? I am actually in the process of converting java code to kotlin.

**UPDATE**

I need a static reference to the getter of the ES class, similar to JAVA, where we can do ->

```
Function<ES, SomeClass> ref = ES::getIssue;
```

Comment: its necessary for me to have ref, its being used somewhere else, i just removed the non essential parts of the code.

Comment: Why not `private val ref: Supplier<SomeClass?> = Supplier<SomeClass?> { es -> es.issue`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Because `Supplier` doesn't take an argument?

Comment: That makes sense, but then I just would take a completely different approach. Why *am* I trying to use a Supplier here.

Comment: Can you explain why (in the Java version) we should use Function<> here instead of a Supplier<> ? I understand that logically it should be a Function only, but a getter doesnt accept any arguments right? eg. objectName.getField() ? I guess objectName is not considered an argument? Or is Function<> smart enough to understand that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kotlin, instead of using Supplier, you use functional syntax for the type. In this case, the equivalent of your `Supplier<SomeClass?>` would be `() -> SomeClass?` (assuming ES is an `object` since that's how you used it in your example code):

```
class CSS(/*...*/) {
   private val ref: () -> SomeClass? = ES::issue
}
```

But if you have to use Supplier specifically so it can be easily used with Java code, you can wrap your getter reference in a Supplier implementation:

```
class CSS(/*...*/) {
   private val ref: Supplier<SomeClass?> = Supplier(ES::issue)
}
```

**Update**
If you want the getter without a specific instance of the class, similar to `Function<ES, SomeClass>` in Java, then you need to make `ES` a parameter of the function.

Either

```
private val ref: (ES) -> SomeClass? = ES::issue
```

or

```
private val ref: ES.() -> SomeClass? = ES::issue
```

I don't believe there's a way to do this with Supplier, but I don't think you could do it in Java with Supplier either.

Comment: nope, same error (in both cases respectively) -> Required: () -> someClass?.....Found:
KMutableProperty1<ES, someClass?>

Comment: Is `ES` an object or a class? If it's a class, you need to use an instance of it to reference the property. With `object ES`, this syntax works fine for me: https://pl.kotl.in/H7vo2n0je If it's a class and we pass an instance to `CSS`, we can do it like this: https://pl.kotl.in/lmUE_b1yq

Comment: ES is neither an object nor an instance of a class.
Kindly see update in the question. Ive also capitalised someClass to SomeClass, so it doesnt cause confusion.

Comment: Yup, thanks it works. But just out of curiosity, can you tell me why in the Java version, why are we using a Function<> and not a Supplier<> ? I understand that logically it should be a Function only, but a getter doesnt accept any arguments right? eg. objectName.getField() ? I guess objectName is not considered an argument? Or is Function<> smart enough to understand that?

Comment: Supplier has no input. If your getter is a member of a class (not static), you need an instance of that class to call the getter on. The class instance is the input.